# Where can I download the Doom Classic source code, the iOS port?

Tags: first-person-shooter, open-source

Doom classic source code for iOS was released by id software, but there is no working link on their web site where I could get it from.

Do you know an alternative source to download the Doom Game for iOS?

Comment: You may have seen this analysis, but it bears linking: http://fabiensanglard.net/doomIphone/index.php

Comment: I saw it, and is quite good :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it from "http://www.doomworld.com"

> http://www.doomworld.com/idgames/index.php?id=15906

But getting it from idsoftware directly would be better. I hope they will read your mail and fix the problem.